# Pexpect and Bluetooth Low Energy notifications

Tags: pexpect

I am trying to automate the command line tool gatttool on a Raspberry Pi 3.

I am able to continually receive bluetooth notifications while using the tool manually: keying in the commands line by line using interactive mode.

However, with pexpect I am only able to receive several lines of notifications.

After setting up the correct write sequences to the bluetooth server, the Python script is as shown below:

```
while True:
    self.con.expect('\n')
```

This was done to flush to the logfile (sys.stdout)

Are there any buffer settings that might have tripped me up?

Any guidance will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the default setting for "delaybeforesend" was too fast for the bluetooth device.

Slowing it down to 1 second before sending each command helped to resolve the issue.